# Google Colab Invalid Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I want to use this [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) but using my own dataset.
I was able in Import my data set.  Here is my code:

```
all_image_paths = glob.glob(str(data_dir/'*/*'))
all_image_paths = [pathlib.Path(path) for path in all_image_paths]
print("Total images: ", len(all_image_paths))
train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(all_image_paths, test_size=0.2)
print("Train dataset size: ", len(train_dataset))
print("Test dataset size: ", len(test_dataset))
def load_image(image_file):
input_image, target_image = imageio.imread(image_file), imageio.imread(image_file)

input_image = np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(input_image).resize((256, 256)))

target_image = np.array(PIL.Image.fromarray(target_image).resize((256, 256)))

input_image = (input_image - 127.5) / 127.5

target_image = (target_image - 127.5) / 127.5

input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0)

target_image = np.expand_dims(target_image, axis=0)
return input_image, target_image



real_image, drawing_image = load_image(train_dataset[0])
RealDataSet = tf.constant(real_image);
DrawingDataSet = tf.constant(drawing_image)
print(RealDataSet)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(RealDataSet / 255.0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(DrawingDataSet / 255.0)
```

I am getting an error that says

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-9-11dafe553f4a> in <module>
  1 plt.figure()
  ----> 2 plt.imshow(RealDataSet / 255.0)
  3 plt.figure()
  4 plt.imshow(DrawingDataSet / 255.0)

  5 frames
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
697                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
698             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
--> 699                             .format(self._A.shape))
700 
701         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 256, 256, 4) for image data
```

What is wrong with the shape (1,256,256,4) ?

Code Update:

```
NewRealDataSet = tf.reshape(RealDataSet, (256,256,4))
NewDrawingDataSet = tf.reshape(DrawingDataSet,(256,256,4))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(NewRealDataSet / 255.0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(NewDrawingDataSet / 255.0)
```

Now I got some warnings:
WARNING:matplotlib.image:Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
WARNING:matplotlib.image:Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

and the graphs are blank. Like in the tutorial you can see a image in their graph but you cant see anything in my graph
see:
[image: image chart]

question my drawings all have a transparent background, could that be cause this problem ?

Update:
[image]

Comment: Because it wants (256,256,4).  It doesn't know what format a 4D thing would be.  You can use `reshape` to do that at no cost.

Comment: @TimRoberts I  tried your suggestions and my error did go away, but now I have there warning and my image is still not displaying

Comment: It looks like your two images get returned from your function in the range (-0.5, 0.5).  Is that right?  If so, then it's clearly wrong to divide them by 255.  You need to add 0.5, to make the range (0,1).

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you are right , I just updated the post with a picture of the code output.

Comment: @TimRobets ok so that worked! adding 0.5. a few questions. How did you know to add 0.5 ?

Comment: @TimRobets, ok another program both the images are of Drawing but one should be of the  real person. I think it did not get divide it right.

Comment: Because you did `(image - 127.5) / 127.5`.  That suggests your arrays were running -0.5 to +0.5.  The image libraries expect 0 to 1.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered ?

Comment: There are no answers, so there's nothing to mark.

Comment: It was the 1st thing you said